# для JSON аналог SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, json, join

с сервера приходят два JSONа . как самым простым способом сделать по ним операцию
аналогичную SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN - может есть какой то JavaScript метод или функция ?

Comment: Зависит от структуры этих самых json, что куда надо вложить и что они вообще такое объекты или массивы. Общий алгоритм - проходить циклом по ключам первого объекта/массива и искать соответствующие ключи во втором, склеивать. Если найдено более одного элемента во втором - размножать записи

Comment: ну два JSON а - объекты , подобные двум реляционным таблицам ,которые можно связать по ключевому полю . понятно что можно делать это руками - то есть искать ключ из одного JSON а в другом - в том то и вопрос - нет ли какого то средства подобного запросу SQL - то есть не писать это все , а вызвать метод с указанием ключа и все)

Comment: Встроенного в язык нет. Да и собственно зачем, если "написать" заключается в максимум 3 строках кода